# Building a small page with an image with 3 buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a small webpage with 3 buttons, like this, with a background image:
[image]

By hovering on one of the buttons, the image should change using js.

What would be the best way to achieve this effect?
I tried with background-image,  but when the image changes it doesn't change instantly. It first makes the page white, I don't know why.

Thanks.

///edit:

```js
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
   {
    document.querySelector(".gaming").addEventListener("mouseover", function()
    {
        document.querySelector(".container").style.backgroundImage = 'url(1.png)';
    });
    document.querySelector(".media").addEventListener("mouseover", function()
    {
        document.querySelector(".container").style.backgroundImage = 'url(2.png)';
    });
    document.querySelector(".forum").addEventListener("mouseover", function()
    {
        document.querySelector(".container").style.backgroundImage = 'url(3.png)';
    });  
   });
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 1080px;
}

.gaming 
{
position: absolute;
height:100%;
}

.media
{

}

.forum {
    position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portal</title>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
  <image class="image-portal"></image>
  <a class="gaming">1</a>
  <a class="media">2</a>
  <a class="forum">3</a>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

That's how I tried to do it. Now I'm trying to position the buttons. Should I change the image src instead of adding a backgroundImage? (also I think I need a handler for mouseleave too).

Comment: I don't think this is the best place to get people to write your code for you. Have you tried anything you could show us?

Comment: I don't need people to write code for me. I just want to know how can this effect can be achieved with best practice. I'll try to code it myself.

Comment: Is it just a switch between one image and another or are you going to be switching to multiple images, on hover?

Comment: Please understand that a *lot* of people come here and write questions like this one, expecting people to write it for them.  Your question doesn't contain what you've tried.  It's hard to help you when we can't see your code.

Comment: I added code. I just wanted ideas on how would be the best way to do it, not code. Thanks though.

Comment: For hover effect showing images I would recommend not even using JS the way you are showing above. Just use the CSS `:hover` selector instead of having to query the DOM for a class each time.

Comment: That would be a better idea. I didn't know why I didn't think about it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the images in advance without any code, just place some `<link rel="preload">` tags in the header like so:

```
<head>
    <link rel="preload" href="1.png" as="image" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="preload" href="2.png" as="image" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="preload" href="3.png" as="image" type="image/png" />
</head>
```

Additional information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Comment: That helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should load the images when you init the page.
You can create an array and then load the images from this array..